# Unable to build C++ binary with -fvtable-verify

Tags: c++, vtable, gcc7, devtoolset

I am trying to enable vtable verification in my project. When I try to use the flag (-fvtable-verify=std) I get an error `g++: error: -fvtable-verify=std is not supported in this configuration`.

Can you help me figure out what is going wrong?

```
[root@eaf114bcd5cc build-debug]# g++ -fvtable-verify=std temp.cc 
g++: error: -fvtable-verify=std is not supported in this configuration
[root@eaf114bcd5cc build-debug]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  
There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@eaf114bcd5cc build-debug]# which gcc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory?   Your installation of gcc is configured, and therefore built, without support of that feature.  One of the options supported by the `configure` script - which is run BEFORE building the compiler from source - is `--enable-vtable-verify` and documentation says that `--disable-vtable-verify` is the default setting.   If you want such support, you'll need to configure and build a version of the compiler to enable it, then install and use that.

Comment: Do you know where I can get the source code to build gcc (same options that devtoolset-7) uses

Comment: gcc.gnu.org for souce code of gcc.   Check you read the license terms.